# How to make a responsive nav-bar using Angular material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to create a navigation bar using [Angular material 2](https://material.angular.io/components/categories/nav)  that collapses in small screens like mobile devices and tablets.

I was only able to find `md-button` but not `md-menu-bar` as was in Angular material.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here is what I used to build my responsive `nav-bar` using Angular2+ Material 2 and flex-layout in `angular-cli` app.

(Please visit [Install Angular Material and Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started))

1) Install flex-layout

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout -save
```

2) Include **flex-layout** in your `app.module.ts`

```
import {FlexLayoutModule} from "@angular/flex-layout";
```

3) Import

```
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 FormsModule,
 HttpModule,
 RoutingModule,
 FlexLayoutModule,
MyOwnCustomMaterialModule // Please visit the link above "Install Angular Material and Angular CDK", and check (Step 3: Import the component modules).
],
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">

    <button mat-button routerLink="/">
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon> 
        {{title}}</button>

    <!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/products">Products</button>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</button>
    </div>
    <button mat-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
     <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>

</mat-toolbar>
<mat-menu x-position="before" #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/products">Products</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</button>
    <!--<button mat-menu-item>Help</button>-->
</mat-menu>
```

app.component.css

```css
.fill-remaining-space {
   /*This fills the remaining space, by using flexbox.  
  Every toolbar row uses a flexbox row layout. */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Note: to test, resize your page.

take a look at [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/tree/master/src/apps/demo-app/src/app/responsive/responsive-show-hide) docs

Comment: works very well.  Thanks for the heads up on the flex-layout.  Had not heard about it.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Cool solution. Just remember FlexLayoutModule.forRoot() was deprecated. we now just use FlexLayoutModule

Comment: wanted to make a small advise: it is probably suitable to use `md-menu-item` in the menu that is shown when collapsed

Comment: angular-material has changed names of most components. This snippet doesn't work as of angular-material 5.0.2

Comment: @Ruben Good question.. I was thinking the same, the first thing to roll-out at Angular would be a simple RESPONSIVE menu, right??

Answer (score 18):

Here is my favorite way of creating a responsive Navigation Bar in Angular. If you use Angular 6, make sure you use a version 6.1+
Working example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6xwte

Example on a smaller screen:
[image: Toolbar on a small screen]

Example on a larger screen:
[image: Toolbar on a large screen]

Here are precise steps how to do it:

1) Install necessary packages. Type in your terminal:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations

npm install @angular/flex-layout --save
```

2) Import necessary modules in your app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {
  MatIconModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule
} from '@angular/material';
```

Remember to add these modules to the imports array below.

3) Add Material Icons link to your index.html 
The link must go before any Angular content.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

4) In your styles.css add an Angular theme and set margins to 0%

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
body{
    margin: 0%;
}
```

5) Add toolbar HTML code in your app.component.html

```html
<div style="height: 100vh;"> 
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
    <a mat-button class="companyName" routerLink="/">
      <span>Site name</span>
    </a>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">
      <a mat-button routerLink="/about-us">About us</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/prices">Prices</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/start-page">Start page</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/offer">Offer</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav color="primary" #sidenav fxLayout="column" mode="over" opened="false" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <div fxLayout="column">
        <a mat-button routerLink="/about-us">About us</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/prices">Prices</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/start-page">Start page</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/offer">Offer</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
      Awesome content
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

6) Style the toolbar in your app.component.css

```css
.companyName{
    font-size: 150%;
}
div {
    overflow: inherit;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 110%;
    white-space: normal;
}
button{
    font-size: 110%;
    min-width: min-content;
}
.example-icon {
    padding: 0 14px;
  }

  .example-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
  .mat-sidenav-content{
      font-size: 200%;
      text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: Currently the menu items are just regular anchor elements. You can style it as you like though. E.g. with a tree https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview or a menu https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Comment: This is the best, most concise answer I have found.

Answer (score 17):

The ***simplest way*** to create a responsive navbar with Material is use the Angular CLI [schematics](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics).

- [Upgrade your Angular project to 6+](https://update.angular.io/) or create a new project
- ng add @angular/material
- ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name=my-nav

*(If you get 'Collection "@angular/material" cannot be resolved' when running ng add @angular/material, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5nRZ.png))*

Then use the generated component `<app-my-nav></app-my-nav>`
Add the above tag to your main component

**Responsive view on Desktop PC:**
[image: Responsive view on Desktop PC]

**Responsive collapsed menu with low resolution:**
[image: Responsive collapsed menu with low resolution]

This was seen originally on [Angular's blog](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4).

Comment: Where is this use of angular cli documented?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `angular2-material` project on github. Here is a list of material design components they have published so far:

https://www.npmjs.com/~angular2-material

Also, I think either `md-sidenav` or `md-toolbar` is what you are looking for.

`md-sidenav` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/sidenav

`md-toolbar` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/toolbar

**Note:** The project is still in alpha release which means there can be breaking changes in their API. Not recommended to use in production.

Answer (score 4):

My crude attempt to modify the answer with a toolbar with drawer implementation with new component names as of angular-material 5.0.2

To do: Need to get CSS of all header links fixed. Menu icon should be transparent.

https://responsivematerial2.stackblitz.io/

```css
.mat-sidenav-container {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.blank-grow {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>home</mat-icon>
        <span mat-line>home</span>
      </a>

      <a mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>backup</mat-icon>
        <span mat-line>Backup</span>
      </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.open()" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span> Big Header</span>
    <span class="blank-grow"></span>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
      <a>
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>home</mat-icon>
        <span mat-line>home</span>
      </a>

      <a>
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>backup</mat-icon>
        <span mat-line>Backup</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Thanks! Based on https://stackblitz.com/angular/yaldykdbaln?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html? Or not?

Answer (score 4):

*I have edited **user2662006**'s answer with some fixes and code optimizations below. Note that my StackOverflow points are currently too low to even grant me the privilege to submit a comment let alone editing.*

1) [Install Angular Material and Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

2) Install flex-layout

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout -save
```

3) Include **flex-layout** in your `app.module.ts`

```
import {FlexLayoutModule} from "@angular/flex-layout";
```

4) Import related material and flex modules

```
imports: [
 ...,
 FlexLayoutModule,
 MatToolbarModule,
 MatIconModule,
 MatMenuModule,
 MatButtonModule,
],
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-button routerLink="/">
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon> 
        {{title}}
    </button>

    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>

    <div fxLayout="row" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/products">Products</button>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</button>
    </div>
    <button mat-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu" fxShow fxHide.gt-sm>
     <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>

</mat-toolbar>
<mat-menu x-position="before" #menu>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/products">Products</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</button>
</mat-menu>
```

app.component.css

```css
.fill-remaining-space {
   /*This fills the remaining space, by using flexbox.  
  Every toolbar row uses a flexbox row layout. */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Notes:

- resize your page to test responsive layout
- take a look at the [flex-layout API docs](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation)

Comment: How to add nested menu ?

Answer (score 3):

My presentation, [Create Enterprise UIs That Your Users Will Love](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1yXMuzIqlWcF2RRkBgg8B7crQSN4CMtW91d6wBt_QeuE/edit?usp=sharing), covers some of these patterns for Angular Material. The links to the StackBlitz examples are in the speaker notes.

Responsive Button Bar with an Overflow menu: 
This could be placed in or under the TopNav.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-responsive-button-bar?file=app%2Fbutton-bar%2Fbutton-bar.component.ts

Dynamic Nested TopNav Menu: 
Note that this menu is not fully accessible. More work is needed to fully support a good a11y experience.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu?file=app/app.component.ts

Dynamic Nested SideNav Menu:
If you use the Transform Pattern to switch your TopNav to a SideNav on mobile, this shows how to build a dynamic SideNav menu.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-sidenav-menu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

You can build a responsive menu by using `mat-toolbar`, `mat-sidenav` and `flex-layout` (`fxFlexFill`, ...).

[See Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout?file=src/app/app.component.html).

[More info...](https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/responsive-navbar-angular-flex-layout)